# Best way to handle temporary value in swift using coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying figure out what would be the best option to save some info into cache. I want it to be in there until notification pops out and button is pressed. I am already done everything else but I do not know what is the best solution for handling temporary values in cache. I need to use them even if app is closed. Is `CoreData` the best solution with `NSUserDefaults`? Lets assume that I have an array: `var myArray = []`
and I have textField. Now I want that `texField` input to be in array and if notification category button is pressed it deletes the first array item from the `myArray`. I need all this even if app is closed. Faulty code is inside "**".

**Edit:** The main problem is that how can delete every time the last value from array? It is not working if app is closed but works if it is opened.

This is what i've done so far.
This is whre I call out notification and it's action:

This is my array: `var myArray = [String]()`

Here I add object into array:

And now if notification is fired and button is pressed I would like to fire this function to delete first object from array:

Comment: What have you tried? You've got a decent whack of code here; have you tried putting it all together? What *specific* problems do you see?

Comment: @dcsohl All my code is together. I just splitted it for this question. The main problem is that I need to store some value into cache and I do not know what would be the best way to do it. Is it CoreData with NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults. They are accessable if the app is closed or open. 
Read more about NSUserDefaults [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUserDefaults/standardUserDefaults)

**Saving Example:**

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nameField.text!, forKey: "name")
```

**Retrieving Example**

Best Practice

```
if let predicate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("name") {
//NSUserDefaults has a value
} else {
 //NSUserDefaults does not has a value
}
```

Comment: @EricD. Sorry you told me that before!

Comment: @Alexander so I can do like this?

var nimi = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nameField.text!, forKey: "name")
        let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName(nimi)

Comment: @MaeseppTarvo i updated my answer hope this helps!

Comment: @MaeseppTarvo if my answer solved your problem kindly mark it as the right answer. Thnx

Comment: @Alexander sorry but it aint working if app is closed. I used this way to store array into userdefaults and then retrive it and delete at index(0) But not working if app is closed. Only if it is opened. But it is closest answer yet. You got the right answer tick.

Comment: @MaeseppTarvo upload your project on Github and i'll take a look at it!

Comment: @Alexander here you go: https://github.com/MaeseppTarvo/TempCo/tree/master/TempCo

The code is in the ViewController.swift mainly.

Comment: @MaeseppTarvo where are you using the code I provided?

Comment: @Alexander Look at this.  codeshare.io/7YP3J I didn't use it anymore since it didn't work. But I think am gonna give up on this one since coredata is most complicated thing in Swift

Comment: @MaeseppTarvo try this  if let predicate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("name") { }

Comment: @Alexander it deletes only the first entered one.

Comment: @Alexander check it out. I explained more in question. I edited it. I do not understand why it deletes only one from the NSUserDefaults?